# Selective update mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
ID Skills
1 Python | Perl |
2 C# | Python |
3 Java | C++ | Perl |
```

The query should add the skill under skills if the skill doesn't exist but not add it, if it does.
For example,

```
Update t1 set Skills = Concat(Skills,'Python | ') where ID = '1'
```

should not add python to the existing skills as it already exists.

but

```
Update t1 set Skills = Concat(Skills,'Python | ') where ID = '3'
```

should update `3`

```
ID Skills

3 Java | C++ | Perl | Python |
```

I am able to concat but not conditional concat

Thanks

Comment: Why use a relational database and then do this to it? Follow normalization instead of jamming lists into fields.

Comment: @DigitalChris I agree with you but the list is imported from a csv file directly to the database..

Comment: You say that, but then here you're trying to update the records. The beast you've created is already biting you. The correct thing to do is to read the CSV data and import relationally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `not like` on `skills` field.

```
Update t1 
  set Skills = Concat(Skills,'Python | ')
where Skills not like '%Python |%'
```